# AppCache vs Service Workers

Tags: appcache, service-workers

I am looking around to create an offline HTML5 app to be used in both Android and iOS (I do not have the means to create a native iOS app), but when looking up some technology I find this interesting conundrum:

From the [AppCache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Using_the_application_cache) docs:

> **Deprecated**
>   This feature has been removed from the Web standards. Though some browsers may still support it, it is in the process of being dropped. Do not use it in old or new projects. Pages or Web apps using it may break at any time.
>   [...] Use Service Workers instead.

But, when I check the docs for [Service Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers) I get:

> **This is an experimental technology**
>   Because this technology's specification has not stabilized, check the compatibility table for usage in various browsers. Also note that the syntax and behavior of an experimental technology is subject to change in future versions of browsers as the specification changes.

So, if I choose the one, my app will break in the future. When I choose the other, it might not work at all on all devices I want to support.

What is the best way to continue now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use AppCache, then migrate to Service Workers as soon as it's finalized. The browsers won't kill AppCache until Service Workers are finished.

And if they do, you are screwed no matter what choice you've made, so there's nothing you can do in that case.

Comment: Thanks. I have a very small user base (all friends in fact) and I can ask them to install Chrome for me, which has support for Service Workers on all platforms. So, I'll go with that.